# How to detect the key code while keyboard key pressed by using java script

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am developing a website, in order to do some security measures, i need to detect some
 key-code while key board key is pressed.Any one please help me to solve this problem by using java script or any other method...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why did you tag c# - Are you using asp.net?

Comment: yes i am using asp.net in creating webpage and c# in code behind..

Comment: Here is a bit weird idea.You can load the SWF(System.Windows.Forms) assembly,use Application.Run(form) and check the keys pressed with the form.Of course the form will be 0 width and height,but It will need to be focused.I don't know how safe that would be and would not advise using it.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, true);
```

Now you can use a function called  onKeyDown(evt) and see which key was pressed with:

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 38: /* Up arrow was pressed */
            //Do something
            break;
        case 40: /* Down arrow was pressed */
            //Do something
            break;
        case 37: /* Left arrow was pressed */
            //Do something
            break;
        case 39: /* Right arrow was pressed */
            break;
    }
```

}

I hope this helps :D

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will try your code and tell feedback.

Comment: this is supposed to work fine. I've been using it for some time although my advice, if you are going into button pressing, be cautious  you will have to take into account alot of stuff (delete stuff with delete key, for example, clashes if you have any input-type-text and user presses delete while typing).

Comment: Sorry mario, i can't able to under stand your code. can you please provide me some examples, how to implement in a web page.. thanks in advance...

Comment: thanks mario, i am still having one doubt that where i should put this code "window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, true);" in the page...

Comment: @Achshar is right though, why don't you tell us more about what you what to achieve :)? I might be able to provide a more suited answer to your problem.

Comment: The "window.addEventListener" can go anywhere in your script. 
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, true);
</script>

Comment: thanks mario, i got it and i successfully implemented it.. but i also want print screen key code also while pressing it in key board. can help me get that also.. thanks once again..

Comment: what mario no reply.. are you working on it.. thanks for it if you working in key code detection of print screen. i will also search in net about it. if you get any solution please update to me. thanks in advance...

Comment: Sorry for taking to long, I was looking into it. According to [link](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/What-is-the-list-of-KeyCodes-for-JavaScript-KeyDown-KeyPress-and-KeyUp-events.aspx) the keycode for print screen is 44.

Comment: thanks.. that was useful. but how to detect print screen key is pressed through java script. your code detects only alphabets and numbers. but it not detecting for arrow keys and special keys such as print screen, ctrl ,shift etc..

Comment: My code detects any keystroke, in the "switch" I included you'd have to include all the key codes you need to validate against :)

Comment: Yes mario, i did add your code and also in "switch" i included print screen key code as "case 44:". But still i am not getting it right. i also put debugger in the script and debugged it, still no result...thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Example to get the key code

```
<script>  function handleEvent(oEvent) {
                    var oTextbox = document.getElementById("txt1");
                    oTextbox.value += "\n>" + oEvent.type;
                    oTextbox.value += "\n    target is " +
                    (oEvent.target ||   Event.srcElement).id;
                    oTextbox.value += "\n    keyCode is " + oEvent.keyCode;}
</script>
         <body>
             <P>Type some characters into the first textbox.</p>
             <P><textarea id="txtInput" rows="15" cols="50"
              onkeypress="handleEvent(event)"></textarea></p><P><textarea id="txt1" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea></p>
         </body>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will try your code and tell feedback.

Comment: Srikanth, it is showing java script run time error while i try to type a text in the text area. It is showing an error in the line   onkeypress="handleEvent(event)"

Comment: Made some changes check it now.

Comment: thanks srikanth i worked fine. if suppose i pressed direction arrows or print screen key, your code is not getting me key code. can you please help me in that key code detection also... thanks once again.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptkey.shtml

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will try your code and tell feedback.